Reference a typescript class in jsdoc
I've been documenting my JS using jsdoc and am now converting to d.ts files in order to have these exported as types from my package. I want to keep things as DRY as possible.
declare class CallHistory {
    constructor(globalConfig: FetchMockConfig, router: Router);
    ...
}
export default CallHistory

/**
 * @import CallHistory from '../types/CallHistory';
 */

class CallHistory {
    constructor(globalConfig, router) {
        /** @type {CallLog[]} */
        this.callLogs = [];
        this.config = globalConfig;
        this.router = router;
    }
}

I'm getting warnings that globalConfig and router "implicitly has an 'any' type."
I've tried adding /** @type {CallHistory} */, /** @class {CallHistory} */, /** @class CallHistory */, /** @class */, /** @type {typeof CallHistory} */ in order to get the methods to make use of the types from the class definition in the CallHistory.d.ts file, but none work.
How do I get the typechecker to understand that my js class is the implementation of the ts class?

.d.ts files are intended for use when importing a JavaScript library into a TypeScript project; i.e. they provide type annotations to users of a JavaScript library's, not the implementation itself.
The closest you can get to this as far as I know is by structuring your project such that your .d.ts files for each module are in the same directory as your .js files like such:

/

CallHistory.d.ts
CallHistory.js
index.js



That way, while CallHistory.js itself has no type annotations, every other file in the project that uses it does. For example, if index.js starts with:
import CallHistory from './CallHistory';

then the imported CallHistory in index.js will be properly type annotated:

The only other option to both have type annotations and have them work in the implementation file (as far as I'm aware) would be to use JSDoc exclusively and generate the .d.ts files during the build step or when pushing to a remote repo.

Thanks. I guess I might refocus my efforts on making sure the generated d.ts files are better (some of the generated types don't match my jsdoc types - falling back to any sometimes, even though my jsdoc definitions are valid)
